# is it prohibited to use transition interval same as redraw interval?

Tags: d3.js

I've been trying D3 for a day or two now.  So I'm a D3 newbie but have lots of C/C++, Java, PHP, Javascript, etc background.

I started from the tutorials page github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials, and went fairly meticulously through
 - Introduction
 - Three Little Circles
 - Thinking with Joins
 - How Selections Work
first trying examples verbatim, sometimes trying different changes to see if I understand the results.

I then jumped to A Bar Chart, Part 1, and Part 2.

I ended up with results pretty much exactly as expected by the end of Part 2.  The tutorial only has code fragments and I don't see a spot in the tutorial where it says "here is the full finished result you should end up with", nonetheless I end up with this http://jsbin.com/oqetuw/2/edit and it looks to be working identically to the tutorial.

Note for those who haven't tried this tutorial, the key points I'm asking about are the redraw interval, 1500 ms, the transition duration, 1000 ms, and the transition ease function, which the tutorial doesn't use or specify, but I've googled to find that it defaults to cubic-in-out.

As my goal is for a continuous smooth scrolling across the screen, I changed the redraw interval to 1000, and the transition ease function to "linear", and the result is here http://jsbin.com/ijumuv/1/edit

And these are the only changes as shown here:

```
$ diff tut2.09.html tut2.10.html
33c33
< }, 1500);
---
> }, 1000);
78a79
>         .ease("linear")
82a84
>         .ease("linear")
86a89
>         .ease("linear")
```

The strange behaviour, and thus the question is, why do occasionally the bars that reach the left edge seem to bounce back and accumulate from left to right, behind the main bars? (and also occasionally get cleared)

Undoing only the 1500 -> 1000 change, the problem seems never to happen (so it is scrolling every 1.5 s, with each scroll duration being 1 s).  So it would seem maybe if D3 is busy still doing the transition, it fails to remove them?  or some other explanation I can't figure yet.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there are issues with d3 transitions. When the interval and duration are both 1000, there is high chance for the redraw operations to occur before the prior `transition()` on that selection is finished. And that messes with the data binding, or something along those lines.

I [modified your code](http://jsbin.com/utetag/1/edit) such that it continuously checks whether the previous redraw transition has finished before calling the next one. This is by no means "good javascript", but it does illustrate the issue, and some way around it. To understand what I added, just look for all occurrences of `__readyForNext` in the code. It should make sense.

Comment: As you say this isn't good javascript, but thanks for the reply.  For future readers, I've just stopped using transition at all.  My graph bars are narrow enough, I can just set the position to the new position and it scrolls smoothly enough.