# minimal cubism.js horizon chart example (TypeError: callback is not a function)

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I'm having a devil of a time going from any code found on the d3 and cubism API pages to altering things to work with what I need them to do...

I'm trying to follow the steps for a Horizon graph as listed here https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Horizon  but I don't have a Cube or Graphite data source.

So I'm trying to make a minimal example metric from mbostock's answer here 
[Using Other Data Sources for cubism.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526058/using-other-data-sources-for-cubism-js)
and/or the random-value-returning metric example here
https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context

I guess on that Context API page, where it explains the parameters to context.metric(), I don't understand the part "...and the callback function for when results are available".  I have the following on my server and when I view/refresh in my browser I get "TypeError: callback is not  a function" in my browser's console:

```
            <body> 
                <div class="mag"></div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

var myContext = cubism.context();

var myHoriz = myContext.horizon()
        .metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
                var values = [];
                start = +start;
                stop = +stop;
                while (start < stop) {
                        start += step;
                        values.push(Math.random());
                }
                callback(null, values);
        });

d3.select(".mag").selectAll("p")
        .data([1, 2, 3, 7])             // the "times" for which I want to graph the data
        .enter().append("p")
        .call(myHoriz);

                </script>
        </body>
```

Oh (edit), I should add, the code does run, in that I do get a document with four paragraphs added into the div, and the text contents of each paragraph are the numbers 1, 2, 3, 7.  So I guess at least the select(), data(), enter(), and append() bits are working.

Comment: It might be easier to start from [a pure D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1483226) unless you're planning on using cubism-specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks Lars for the comment... Actually, even Line Chart http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 would be fine, as there is nothing in particular about the Horizon chart I need.  But it just seems I am forced to choose from only two chart types (Horizon and Comparison) within cubism, and I do eventually need the scrolling-every-second functionality which it seems cubism.js is good at, no?

Comment: The scrolling every second functionality is explained in [this D3 tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).

Comment: Lars: yes that tutorial describes scrolling every second, but not with a step, size, serverDelay, smartly fetching a big range initially from an http json request, then small incremental updates, etc, already handled for you like cubism.  And yes I had gone through that tutorial early on but had hit other snags, though not insurmountable ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239407/is-it-prohibited-to-use-transition-interval-same-as-redraw-interval ).  Still it seems cubism gives most of what I need, I just need the horizon area-looking graph to be more line-graph like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing [horizon.metric](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Horizon#wiki-metric) with [context.metric](https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Context#wiki-metric).  It is `context.metric` that takes a function of the signature you're defining.

Answer (score 2):

Okay Scott Cameron's point got me over the hurdle.  I'll "answer" here as well with the resulting working code for future readers.  Still not as minimal of an example as I'd like, but eliminates the error, and I'll ask a follow-up in a new question for making it more minimal.

```
            <body> 
                <div class="mag"></div>

                <script type="text/javascript">

var myContext = cubism.context();

var myMetr = myContext.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
        var values = [];
        start = +start; 
        stop = +stop;
        while (start < stop) { 
                start += step;
                values.push(Math.random());
        }       
        callback(null, values);
});     

var myHoriz = myContext.horizon()
        .metric(myMetr);

d3.select(".mag").selectAll("p")
        .data([1, 2, 3, 7])
        .enter().append("p")
        .call(myHoriz);

                </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: Update: I've managed to make a more minimal example (I find it simpler to understand with extraneous formatting, etc removed), taking 2 lines off the final d3.select section, and several lines out of the myContext.metric section, AND it grabs a .json file from a URL, shown here (with follow-up question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522085/more-minimaler-cubism-js-horizon-chart-from-json-example  Hope it helps someone.